# Creating a linked list in C

Tags: c, linked-list

I am currently trying to make a linked list and initialize it within a function. It looks like this:

```
void add_forest(node_t *head, unsigned char value)
{
    int key;
    node_t *current = head;
    while (current->next != NULL)
    {
        current = current->next;
    }

}

int main()
{
    node_t *head;
    *head = init_forest(); //error here
}
```

I am currently getting a segfault at the following area in my code and can not figure out why. I am creating the head in `init_forest()` and then passing back in the main. When I go through the `init_forest()` the tree does become built. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please add the definition of the structure type, and indent the code!

Comment: I'm suspicious that the line `current->next = head = (node_t *)malloc(sizeof(node_t));` assigning to `head` in `add_forest()` is to blame.

Comment: Also learn to use the debugger.  gdb is your friend!

Comment: I am using gdb but can not figure out why it is giving me the seg fault there. I also updated my code above.

Comment: `return *head;` seems a little sketchy, since you change head in `current->next = head = (node_t *)malloc(sizeof(node_t));`.

I take that back, the second time you enter add_forest, in `while(current->next != NULL)` you are dereferencing a likely null object (since you changed the contents of head in the previous call to add_forest). Maybe?

Comment: Off topic, but setting `head = NULL` and then checking `if (head==NULL)` two lines later in `init_forest` is rather unnecessary.

Answer (score 3):

The immediate problem is in `main()`:

```
node_t *head;
*head = init_forest();
```

`head` is an uninitialized pointer; you can't dereference it, and you don't actually want to.  You should be using:

```
node_t *head = init_forest();
```

But you then need to ensure that `init_forest()` returns a `node_t *`, rather than a `node_t` value.  This is the more orthodox style for such linked list management functions.  You allocated the structure in the function; if you return a copy of the structure rather than a pointer to the structure, you're leaking memory (and you end up with other problems later).

Comment: I tried to do that and I get the following compile error: error: incompatible types when initializing type ‘struct node_t *’ using type ‘node_t’

Comment: See the update...you need to fix `init_forest()` to return a `node_t *`, with at least the consequential change that `return *head;` becomes `return head;`.